# Selecting a DOM target with jQuery traversing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to update the content of `.help-block` dynamically with jQuery but not sure why I am not able to target the `.help-block`. I know that we can simply use `$('.help-block').text(....` but I need to do this through jQuery traversing mechanism like `find()` or `next()` and `first()`, but none of them did the job.

```js
$(function() {

  $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function() {
    $("#selector").find('.help-block').html($(this).text());
    $("#selector").next('.help-block').html($(this).text());
    $("#selector").parent().find('.help-block').html($(this).text());
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <label class="control-label" for="new-cu-emailinput"></label>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="selector" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Please Select From the List<i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="selector">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <span class="help-block pull-right"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selectors are wrong. Try like following.

```
 $("#selector").closest('.dropdown').next('.help-block').html($(this).text());
```

Answer (score 0):

Only to show that jQuery is really not needed for such tasks, here's the equivalent vanilla JS solution:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',
  () =>  { 
    for (const link of document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-menu li a')) { 
      link.addEventListener(
        'click', 
        () => link
          .closest('div.dropdown')
          .nextElementSibling
          .textContent = link.textContent)
    }
  }
);
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <label class="control-label" for="new-cu-emailinput"></label>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="selector" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Please Select From the List<i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="selector">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <span class="help-block pull-right"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```